# What do the symbols in the Redis server logfile mean?

Tags: logging, redis

When I open the logfile for Redis called "server_log.txt" I notice different symbols in the column just before the column with the actual message. For instance, here are a couple of lines from the file (notice the "*" and "#"):

```
[2004] 11 Nov 10:24:36.721 * Background saving started by pid 8172
[2004] 11 Nov 10:24:36.911 # fork operation complete
```

I also see that some of the messages are prepended with either "+" or "-":

```
[788] 11 Nov 19:10:44.803 # +tilt #tilt mode entered
[788] 11 Nov 19:11:14.903 # -tilt #tilt mode exited
```

Does anyone know what these symbols mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the  "*" and "#" symbols, these indicate the severity of the message:

```
.  // DEBUG
-  // INFO
*  // NOTICE
#  // WARNING
```

For the '+' and '-', these can sometimes indicate a mode/flag that is on/off.  It's not always mode/flag, as shown in this list of sentinel pub/sub channel-names : https://redis.io/docs/manual/sentinel/